# Jenkins git Refspec to build master and any v* branches

Tags: git, jenkins, git-branch, git-refspec

Our developers use temporary branches but I only want to build any commits to `master` and any `v*` branches (e.g. `v1.0`, `v1.0`, `v1.1`, etc.)

I am trying the following in the Refspec field:

```
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master 
+refs/heads/v*:refs/remotes/origin/v*
```

but jenkins kicks out the following error:

```
stderr: fatal: Invalid refspec '+refs/heads/v*:refs/remotes/origin/v*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue was my git client was 1.9.1. I am going to change my docker base image to ubuntu 16 which should have a newer git client.

verified that this resolved the issue. I upgraded to ubuntu 16 which had a git cli of 2.7.4 and now the refspec is working as intended.